# Datazen, I don't see datasource after added it

Tags: database, datasource, datazen-server

I have a problem with datazen. I added new datasource with success but after i dont't see it and I can't select It. In the ravenbd I see it! 
This's happen 2 days ago.

Any idea???
Thank you for any help.

Best regards.